# Stuck on a question in Stein & Shakarchi, Complex Analysis about meromorphic functions and the logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis

This is Problem 1 from Stein & Shakarchi, Complex Analysis, Chapter 3 (pg 108). I found it to be an interesting result but not sure how to get there:

Consider a holomorphic map on $D_1(0)$ s.t. $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ and $f(0) = 0$.

Does there exist $r>0$ s.t $\forall f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ with $f(0) = 0$, we have $D_r(0) \subset f(\mathbb D)$.

a) Show, with no further restrictions on $f$, no such $r$ exists. Consider the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ holomorphic in $\mathbb D$ s.t. $1/n \notin f(\mathbb D)$. Compute $f'_n(0)$.

b) Assume, also, that $f'(0) = 1$. Show that there still does not exist an $r>0$ that satisfies the condition.

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For part a), we can simply take $f_n(z) = \frac{z}{n}$, then $f_n(\mathbb{D}) = D_{1/n}(0)$, and since $\frac{1}{n}\to 0$, the result follows. We have $f_n'(0) = \frac{1}{n}\to 0$, which makes it easy.

Part b), which demands we restrict our attention to functions with $f'(0) = 1$, is more interesting. It is easy to find a(n entire, if we desire so) holomorphic $f$ with $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$ and $-1\notin f(\mathbb{D})$; $f(z) = \sin z$ will do, or even $f(z) = z$. Then $1+f(z)$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$, and therefore

$$g_n(z) = (1+f(z))^n - 1$$

satisfies $g_n(0) = 0$ and does not attain the value $-1$ on $\mathbb{D}$. But $g_n'(0) = n(1+f(0))^{n-1}\cdot f'(0) = n\cdot 1^{n-1}\cdot 1 = n$, so

$$f_n(z) = \frac{1}{n}g_n(z) = \frac{(1+f(z))^n-1}{n}$$

is holomorphic where $f$ is, satisfies the two conditions $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n'(0) = 1$, and does not attain the value $-\frac{1}{n}$ on $\mathbb{D}$.